# Send Mail with Attachment using Sitecore Forms

Tags: sitecore-forms

How we can send email with attached file, while clicking form submit button?

We are currently using Sitecore 9 Update 2 with SXA 1.7.2.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can create a custom action "send email" based on: [Send-E-mail-Action-to-Sitecore-9-Forms](https://www.nishtechinc.com/Blog/2018/April/Send-E-mail-Action-to-Sitecore-9-Forms), add to action's editor dialog/view model link to media item. And when on action executing add to mail attachments linked media item.

Answer (score 1):

There is no functionality like that in your version of Sitecore, neither it is in latest Sitecore 9.1.

You have two options:

1. Create your custom Field Type "FileUpload" inspiring by official documentation by Sitecore -> https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-rating-element-with-property-editor.html .
2. Use code from Sitecore Forms Extensions github repository https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions and specifically this part -> https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/tree/master/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/Fields/FileUpload.

   It should have really simple model:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Globalization;
   using System.Web;
   using Feature.FormsExtensions.Business.FileUpload;
   using Sitecore;
   using Sitecore.Data.Items;
   using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Validation;

   namespace Feature.FormsExtensions.Fields.FileUpload
   {
       [Serializable]
       public class FileUploadModel : ValueNotValidatedInputViewModel<IStoredFile>
       {
           [NonSerialized]
           private HttpPostedFileBase file;
           private const string AllowedContentTypesParam = "Allowed Content Types";
           private const string MaxFileSizeParam = "Max File Size";

           [DynamicRequired]
           [DynamicValidation]
           public virtual HttpPostedFileBase File
           {
               get => file;
               set => file = value;
           }

           public string AllowedContentTypes { get; set; }
           public int MaxFileSize { get; set; }

           protected override void InitItemProperties(Item item)
           {
               base.InitItemProperties(item);
              AllowedContentTypes = StringUtil.GetString(item.Fields[AllowedContentTypesParam]);
              MaxFileSize = MainUtil.GetInt(item.Fields[MaxFileSizeParam]?.Value, 0);
           }

           protected override void UpdateItemFields(Item item)
           {
               base.UpdateItemFields(item);
               item.Fields[AllowedContentTypesParam]?.SetValue(AllowedContentTypes, true); 
               item.Fields[MaxFileSizeParam]?.SetValue(MaxFileSize.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),true);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: While submitting the submit button, i'm getting null value for the File