# Attaching a File to an Email sent from Sitecore Forms Extensions

Tags: sitecore-forms

I'm using the [File Upload field](http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/sitecoreformsextentions/1.8.3/contenteditordoc/customfields/fileupload.html) in sitecoreformsextentions module with SXA 1.8 and Sitecore 9.02. According to the [documentation for the send email action](http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/sitecoreformsextentions/1.8.3/contenteditordoc/sendmail.html) it should be attached to the email:

[image]

---

And it should be possible to get the value in the email template:

[image]

---

However whilst the file is uploaded to the rootstoragepath it is not attached to the email.

Is there something I need to do to wire this up with tokens or some config settings I'm missing somewhere?

I read this post but I'm using a different version and it looks to be supported from the docs: [Send Mail with Attachment using Sitecore Forms](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16063/send-mail-with-attachment-using-sitecore-forms/16128)

Answer (score 0):

In the email template, you just place the name of the field in { } brackets.

In the email HTML below, the `{File Upload}` is my upload field.

```
<strong>Contact Us Form&nbsp;Submission</strong><br />
<br />
First:&nbsp; {FirstName} <br />
Last:&nbsp; {LastName}<br />
Email:&nbsp; {Email}<br />
Subject:&nbsp; {Subject}<br />
Uploaded File:&nbsp; {File Upload}<br />
<p>Message<br />
{Message}</p>
<br />
```

This is the field in the editor

[image]

Ends up like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris that didn't work for me, I got this error:

File:
Unsupported field type Feature.FormsExtensions.Fields.FileUpload.FileUploadModel

Comment: Maybe it's a version thing or something, thats what I assumed would work though. My other fields come through fine when using brackets like that.

Comment: @AdamSeabridge I wonder if you are uploading a non-supported file type? I see this template `/sitecore/templates/Modules/FormExtensions/Fields/FileUploadField/Validation/Allowed Content Types`, trying to understand how it works.