# Attaching a file uploaded from sitecore forms in the Email

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am creating a sitecore form where I need to attach the uploaded file in the form to the Send Email which comes OOTB in the sitecore forms.

I am not finding any options to attach the files.

Is there a way to attach the files which comes from the form fields?

Any help on this will be great

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to find that file that you uploaded through file upload?

Comment: Yes Sumit, the file/files uploaded through form field file upload

Comment: Did you check this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31059/attaching-a-file-to-an-email-sent-from-sitecore-forms-extensions

Comment: Yes, Its not working. My version of sitecore is 10.1 and sxa 11200

Comment: This is something that is possible in the "Send Email" submit action that is included in the Sitecore Forms Extensions: https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/
This is a separate module that you will have to install before you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

In the Execute method of the `SendEmailAction` class, where the `FormSubmitContext` is a method argument, we can access the File Upload fields, assuming there can be more than one, get the stream of data, and add it to the attachments list. Please see the code snippet below:

```
var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
var uploadFieldList = formSubmitContext.Fields
      .Where(f => f.GetType() == typeof(FileUploadViewModel));
if (uploadFieldList != null && uploadFieldList.Count() > 0)
{
  foreach (var uploadField in uploadFieldList)
  {
    if (uploadField != null)
    {
      var uploadFieldVM = (FileUploadViewModel)uploadField;
      if (uploadFieldVM.Files != null && uploadFieldVM.Files.Count > 0)
      {
        for (var i = 0; i < uploadFieldVM.Files.Count; i++)
        {
          var uploadFile = uploadFieldVM.Files[i];
          uploadFile.InputStream.Position = 0;
          attachments.Add(new Attachment(
              uploadFile.InputStream, 
              uploadFile.FileName, 
              uploadFile.ContentType));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**More details and Credit:** https://cristinadragos.wordpress.com/2021/03/18/sitecore-forms-and-attaching-the-uploaded-files-when-sending-emails/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Sumit, that helps.. The custom submit action is getting executed but the uploaded file is not getting attached. I debugged, the file exists in the mailMessage object. Anything else need to be configured?

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a Custom Send Email submit action in Sitecore Forms.

This can be achieved in 2 steps

1. Create a class that inherits from `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Processing.SubmitActions.SendEmail` and write your custom logic.
2. Add a Custom Submit Action under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Submit Actions`

And in the `Execute` method, you can get all the fields along with your uploaded file using this code.

```
if (uploadFieldList != null && uploadFieldList.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var uploadField in uploadFieldList)
                        {
                            if (uploadField != null)
                            {
                                var uploadFieldVM = (FileUploadViewModel)uploadField;
                                if (uploadFieldVM.Files != null && uploadFieldVM.Files.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < uploadFieldVM.Files.Count; i++)
                                    {
                                        var uploadFile = uploadFieldVM.Files[i];
                                        uploadFile.InputStream.Position = 0;
                                        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(
                                            uploadFile.InputStream,
                                            uploadFile.FileName,
                                            uploadFile.ContentType));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Refer to this article for the full source code.

https://sitecorediaries.org/2021/09/08/creating-custom-submit-action-to-send-the-emails-in-sitecore-forms/

Comment: Thank you Sumit, that helps.. The custom submit action is getting executed but the uploaded file is not getting attached. I debugged, the file exists in the mailMessage object. Anything else need to be configured?

Comment: @SyedAmanulla So you mean you are getting all the fields but not the file using `formSubmitContext.Fields.Where(f => f.GetType() == typeof(FileUploadViewModel))` ?

Comment: I am getting the file in the above mentioned object, and the email is getting triggered. the file is not attached in the email..

Comment: I have updated the picture with debugging values of attachment.. does that give any hint?

Comment: @SyedAmanulla The picture is not too clear. Can you please add it again?

Comment: Thank you @sumit Bhatia and Sumit Helaiya. I have solved this now. You solutions helped. One extra step is that, the  this.MailSender.SendMail(mailMessage); was causing the issue. I got my own send email function to trigger emails with attachment from collected data. I will place the code in answer for reference of others

Answer (score 0):

```
using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Models;
using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields;
using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.SubmitActions;
using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Processing;
using Sitecore.Reflection;
using Sitecore.Services.Core.ComponentModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using KAO.Foundation.Email;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace KAO.Foundation.ExperienceForms.Extensions
{
    public class CustomSendEmail : Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Processing.SubmitActions.SendEmail
    {
        public CustomSendEmail(ISubmitActionData submitActionData) : base(submitActionData)
        {
        }

        private static string GetFieldValue(IViewModel postedField)
        {
            if (postedField.GetType().GetMethod("GetStringValue") != null)
            {
                return ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(postedField, "GetStringValue").ToString();
            }

            return "";
        }

        private static string ReplaceFieldValues(string content, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
        {
            string str = content;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            foreach (IViewModel field in formSubmitContext.Fields)
            {
                str = str.Replace(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", '[', field.Name, ']'), GetFieldValue(field));
            }
            return str;
        }

        private static void AddRecipients(MailAddressCollection mailAddressCollection, string mailAddresses)
        {
            string[] array = (
                from p in mailAddresses.Split(new char[] { ';' })
                select p.Trim() into p
                where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p)
                select p).ToArray<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)array.Length; i++)
            {
                mailAddressCollection.Add(array[i]);
            }
        }

        protected override bool Execute(SendEmailData data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
        {
            bool flag;
            using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                try
                {
                    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ReplaceFieldValues(data.From, formSubmitContext));
                    mailMessage.Subject = ReplaceFieldValues(data.Subject, formSubmitContext);
                    mailMessage.Body = ReplaceFieldValues(data.Body, formSubmitContext);
                    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    AddRecipients(mailMessage.To, ReplaceFieldValues(data.To, formSubmitContext));
                    AddRecipients(mailMessage.CC, ReplaceFieldValues(data.Cc, formSubmitContext));
                    AddRecipients(mailMessage.Bcc, ReplaceFieldValues(data.Bcc, formSubmitContext));
                    #region Attachment 
                    var attachments = new List<Foundation.Email.EmailService.Attachment>();
                    var uploadFieldList = formSubmitContext.Fields
                          .Where(f => f.GetType() == typeof(FileUploadViewModel));
                    if (uploadFieldList != null && uploadFieldList.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var uploadField in uploadFieldList)
                        {
                            if (uploadField != null)
                            {
                                var uploadFieldVM = (FileUploadViewModel)uploadField;
                                if (uploadFieldVM.Files != null && uploadFieldVM.Files.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < uploadFieldVM.Files.Count; i++)
                                    {
                                        var uploadFile = uploadFieldVM.Files[i];
                                        uploadFile.InputStream.Position = 0;
                                        var attach = new Email.EmailService.Attachment
                                        {
                                            Filename = uploadFile.FileName,
                                            Base64FileContents = ConvertToBase64(uploadFile.InputStream),
                                            
                                        };
                                        attachments.Add(attach);                                       
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion
                    KAO.Foundation.Email.Email.SendEmailWithAttachments(mailMessage.From.ToString(), mailMessage.To.ToString(), mailMessage.CC.ToString(), mailMessage.Bcc.ToString(), mailMessage.Subject, mailMessage.Body, attachments.ToArray(), true);
                    flag = true;
                }
                catch (Exception exception1)
                {
                    Exception exception = exception1;
                    this.Logger.LogError(exception.Message, exception, this);
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            return flag;
        }

        private static string ConvertToBase64(Stream stream)
        {
            if (stream is MemoryStream memoryStream)
            {
                return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }

            var bytes = new Byte[(int)stream.Length];

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }
    }
}
```