# File not attached to email sent from "SitecoreFormsExtension" form

Tags: sitecore-forms

I'm using `Sitecore Forms Extension` to build forms, `Sitecore version 10.1`.
I created a form and added a "File Upload" element, and created an automated email campaign.

I'm having a problem that the attached file in the form is not attached to the sent mail, I only get the File Id and File name in the email.

[image]

According to [this link](https://sitecore-forms-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developerdoc/azureblobstorage/) I should be able to add a configuration so that the uploaded files are stored in a blob storage in order to get attached to the email.

I followed the steps and added the patch file to my instance, however, I'm still getting the same result in the sent email.

Any idea what I might be missing in order to be able to attach the uploaded file to the sent email?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attaching a file uploaded from sitecore forms in the Email](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/34214/attaching-a-file-uploaded-from-sitecore-forms-in-the-email)

Comment: @Sumit Bhatia no, he's using a custom send email action, but i'm using the Sitecore forms extension action

Comment: Okay Did you check this one also? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31059/attaching-a-file-to-an-email-sent-from-sitecore-forms-extensions

Comment: @SumitBhatia yes, but i'm working with different Sitecore version (10.1), so the proposed solution didn't work for me. Also, i don't want to build a custom send mail action

Answer (score 1):

I found something that might help you to identify your configuration. While checking the configuration `Feature.FormsExtensions.AzureBlobFileStorageProviders.config` I found that you need to register the serviceType like this in your patch.

```
<services>
    <register serviceType="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.IFileStorageProvider, Sitecore.ExperienceForms"
            implementationType="Feature.FormsExtensions.FileStorageProviders.AzureBlobStorageFileStorageProvider, Feature.FormsExtensions"
            lifetime="Transient"
            patch:instead="*[@serviceType='Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.IFileStorageProvider, Sitecore.ExperienceForms']" />
</services>
```

Check this link for the whole patch file.

https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/blob/master/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/App_Config/Include/Feature/FormsExtensions/Feature.FormsExtensions.AzureBlobFileStorageProviders.config.disabled

**Update:**

You should also check that you have added the processor called `AttachFileUploadProcessor` that is handling the logic to attach file to SendEmail action. Find the whole source code of this processor in this GitHub link.

https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/blob/master/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/SubmitActions/SendEmail/FileAttachment/AttachFileUploadProcessor.cs

Also it should be in your config like this.

```
<pipelines>
      <SendEmail role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or DedicatedDispatch">
        <processor patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Pipelines.SendEmail.SendEmail, Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm']"
                   type="Feature.FormsExtensions.SubmitActions.SendEmail.FileAttachment.AttachFileUploadProcessor, Feature.FormsExtensions" resolve="true" />
      </SendEmail>
```

Check the whole config here with this link.

https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/blob/master/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/App_Config/Include/Feature/FormsExtensions/Feature.FormsExtensions.Processors.config

Try this and hope this will solve your issue.

Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot, i tried this solution, and the file is now uploaded to the blob storage, but it's still not attached to the sent email, any idea what might be missing?

Comment: @AME Did you check in your showconfig if are able to find the AttachFileUploadProcessor. Given in this link https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/blob/master/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/SubmitActions/SendEmail/FileAttachment/AttachFileUploadProcessor.cs