# Sitecore 10.2 - Form FileUpload -

Tags: sitecore-forms

I'm using Sitecore 10.2 and the out-of-the-box Forms module.

I created a form, with a File Upload item. It works fine, the files are uploaded and I'm able to see and download them in the CSV exported file.
Is there a way to include the uploaded file as an attachment in the mail sent via the 'submit action'?
Should also be fine also have the path of the file, in order to create a link.

I've read that the Sitecore-Forms extension might have the feature I need.
But it seems to me that the latest supported version of Sitecore is 10.1 (https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/tree/master/downloads)

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try this one? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31059/attaching-a-file-to-an-email-sent-from-sitecore-forms-extensions

Comment: Use this code to sent attachment with email. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/34214/attaching-a-file-uploaded-from-sitecore-forms-in-the-email

Comment: @SumitBhatia yes, thanks. But it refers to Sitecore-Forms-Extensions, with a different Sitecore version. I don't understand if Sitecore-form-extensions are compatible with Sitecore 10.2

Comment: @SumitHelaiya so, the only way is to create a Custom Send Email submit action. There is no out-of-the-box feature. Thanks!