Unable to Send FileUploadUrl in Email While using out of the box fileupload control in sitecore forms(sitecore 10.3.1)
I am using out of the box File Upload Control. While exporting the form data I receive all the fields with a file upload URL which will download the file. I am trying to send these details over email. However, all the fields are retrieved in the email except the file upload URL.
I receive an error message for the File upload URL:

"Forms.Actions.SendMail.UnsupportedFieldTypeErrorMessage"

FORM

EMAIL

EMAIL EXPORT DATA

EMAIL TEMPLATE


Are you using something differently? I was able to get the FIle upload value properly in my email
Name : SK
Email : sk@sk.com
File Upload : 1c17d9fd-05b4-47bf-83b2-7ccba5fa3c98

I'm utilizing the out-of-the-box File Upload control. I tried to follow the instructions outlined in this article (https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31059/attaching-a-file-to-an-email-sent-from-sitecore-forms-extensions), but encountered an error as mentioned above.
I would like to retrieve the file upload url generated in the file export report (or) Could you help me on customizing the code to enable attachment sending via email upon user form submission(Sitecore forms) while using Headless Next.js?
